# os.system() works, subprocess.run() doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a program on windows using python3.7. I read it's advised to use  `subprocess.run()` instead of `os.system()` but I can't get it to work using `run()`.

The code that works:

```
rc = os.system('my.exe "my project" "my command"')
```

This gives me `rc=-1`, which is what i would expect because the project is set up to fail atm.

The code that doesn't work:

```
command = ['my.exe', '"my project"', '"my command"']
result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

This has `result.returncode=0`, which is not what I expected.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the inner quotes.

Comment: Could also be a PATH problem.

Comment: @melpomene if you write this as an answer I will accept it because it solved my problem. Thank you so much! Only weird thing is that the return code is `4294967295` instead of `-1` but I can absolutely live with that.